# Persisting text validators

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, persistence, validation

I have a java app in which I can choose an object (let's say - a computer name) from a drop down list and then configure it. For each computer in the drop down list there are different configuration fields that need to be configured. I have a table in my DB that maps configuration fields to comptuer. Each row contains a computer name, the configuration field name and the type of the fields.

For example:

```
computer_name | field_name    | type
=======================================
 test1        | ip            | String
---------------------------------------
 test1        | user name     | String
---------------------------------------
 test2        | manage_port   | Number
---------------------------------------
 test3        | creation_date | Date
```

When choosing `test1` from the drop-box in the UI the user will see 2 text box, one for ip and the second for the user name. Each of the text boxes need to be presented to the user and have a validator that checks for a regex. When choosing `test2` I would like to validate that this indeed a number and also the min and max values. For `test3` I need to ensure the date format (again using a regex).

The DB is postgres (Although I guess the solution should apply for every relational DB) and I'm using Spring + Hibernate.

My idea was to create a validator POJO and a DB table for the validator which will contain all of the validations that are possible in different columns. The problem is, that I feel it's a bit redundant to have null columns. In java I guess I would do an abstract `Validator` class that extended by `RegexValidator` class,  `NumberFormatValidator` class, `MinNumberValidator` class, etc... But I don't know how to correctly represent it in the DB (need to remember that it needs to be mapped to each configuration row in the configuration table).

Any suggestions for a better design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with an `@Embedded` entity if you don't have many fields. Just map the fields you might have to table and use JPA's @Embedded option in order to keep thinks object oriented.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate supports [three types of mapping.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html)
     table per class hierarchy,  table per subclass,  table per concrete class

It looks like your case small enough to be 'table per class hierarchy'.